# Extending interface and making a variable optional in the extended one

Tags: typescript

Consider the following example:

```
interface pluginOptions {
    neededProperty: ...neededPropertyType...;
    ... a bunch of other optional properties ...
}

interface myExtendedPluginOptions extends pluginOptions {
    neededProperty?: ...neededPropertyType...;
}
```

What I want to achieve is, that I am using a plugin, which on initialization excepts a property (`neededProperty`) to be set in the options objects that it receives. I would like to write a wrapper class around that plugin, which will feed this option object to the original plugin, but instead of relying that the object be present in the options when I instantiate my wrapper, it will fetch this value in a different way. Basically like this:

```
/** old init */
const plugin = plugin(pluginOptions);

/** new init */
class ExtendedPlugin {
     constructor(neededProperty: ...neededPropertyType..., options: myExtendedPluginOptions) {
         this.plugin = plugin(jQuery.extend(myExtendedPluginOptions, {
              neededProperty: neededProperty
         });
     }
}

const plugin = new ExtendedPlugin(neededProperty, myExtendedPluginOptions);
```

The reason I need this, is that in our framework, we are using different kinds of plugins, and would like to make the usage of all of these plugin uniforms in a way for that to be easier for other developers, to work with them.

Is it possible somehow in typescript definitions, to either:

1. extend an interface **without** some properties of the extending interface?
2. or at the very least, specify somehow that a property that is mandatory in the extended interface, is now optional in the new one

I know, that I could just copy over into a new interface type all of the properties of the old interface, but I don't consider that as an optimal solution, as it needs constant maintenance in case we update the original plugin, and a new property is added or deleted.

In the above example, typescript is complaining about making the extended interfaces neededProperty optional, with the:
`Property 'neededProperty' is optional in type 'myExtendedPluginOptions' but required in 'pluginOptions' ts(2430)`

Comment: https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk

Comment: exactly what I am looking for, thanks! if you convert this to an answer, I will also accept it!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

It comes as a built-in utility type [`Omit<T, K>`](https://www.typescriptlang.org/docs/handbook/utility-types.html#omittk).

```
type myExtendedPluginOptions = Omit<pluginOptions, 'neededProperty'>;
```

would produce a new type that has the same properties as `pluginOptions` but with `neededProperty` excluded entirely.